# Is it normal for mysqld or httpd to be shutdown for any ocational or rare to happen error?

Tags: amazon-ec2, innodb, mysql

I'm running mysql 5.5.34 on AWS EC2 Instance. But today at 3 'O clock my mysqld has stopped leaving me and my whole team in awe. When I head banged to know why I checked in the mysqld.log and found the following trace :

```
140529  3:03:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140529  3:03:49 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140529  3:03:49 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140529  3:03:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140529  3:03:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140529  3:03:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140529  3:03:50 [ERROR] Aborting

140529  3:03:50 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140529 03:03:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ende                  d
```

InnoDB: **Initializing buffer pool is the start of gangrene..**I assume. But I just don't know **why initializing  buffer pool would cause this into a shutdown** and OR It's something else ?

**I have to know why and how this is happening ? What would be the future sentinels/cautions ?**

**I have to know.. I must know.**

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Seems to be a simple lack of memory. You'll need to post the details of the instance size and memory.

Comment: What size instance are you using?

Comment: @datasage instance type or size is t1.micro

Comment: @ianjs instance type or size is t1.micro

Comment: Micro instances are quite resource constrained. Have you tried simply upsizing to a larger instance to see if more memory resolves the issue?

Comment: @ianjs Nope ! This thing happend the very first time to me. So far I have 200-220 visitors on average to the site and database is turned to 1.7 MB so you can guess the load is not that much. But I see **mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12** indicates  131 M memory was needed for the buffer pool which was 128 M  for which **Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool** happened. So If I turn it to Medium Instance  and say we have 1 m visitors per day is that gonna cover it up? How? Is this an issue of scalability ?

Comment: Do you have messages like "Feb  5 03:48:26 app-01 kernel: [3313052.688189] httpd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0" in /var/log/messages ?

Comment: @edam So, you are running into a memory issue. MySQL is trying to allocate memory that does not exist. In the meantime, you should be able to configure mysql to use less memory, but you will need to look at using a larger instance. How many users a single instance can handle depends largely on your application, but ec2 makes it easy to test.

Comment: @datasage I have changed to m3.medium already and it gave 2 or 3 times crash (both httpd and mysqld.. of course with differnt log messages) and now for average 50 users (traffic) it's running okay for 2 days.

Comment: I suspected oom killer, but if it's not you have to figure out why MySQL crashes. (It's obvious why it can't start)